# Initializing multiple rows of an SQLite3 database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sql-insert

I have a simple database tables of 2 columns, the first being a lightbulb `id`, and the 2nd being an integer `status` (0/1) denoting whether the light is on or not. By default all of my light switches are assumed to be off. The number of lightbulbs is fixed, I only need to change the id with each row.

Here is my table:

```
cursor.execute(
    '''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info(
    id integer,
    status integer
    )
    '''

)
```

What is a better way to initialize the table than to manually list each row as follows? (I know the number of lights is fixed to 10).

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO info VALUES(1,0)')
c.execute('INSERT INTO info VALUES(2,0)')
c.execute('INSERT INTO info VALUES(3,0)')

....

....
c.execute('INSERT INTO info VALUES(10,0)')
```

Comment: `executemany()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any operation within the Database, but just iterate within the application by using `range(1,11)` to generate integers starting from 1 upto 10 :

```
....
c = con.cursor()
....
for i in range(1,11):
    c.execute('INSERT INTO info VALUES(?,0)',(i,))

con.commit()
```

Comment: It's much better to use `VALUES(?)` and have the db interpolate as a habit. See docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: thank you @chthonicdaemon for the caveat. I think you especially mean vulnerability against injection ...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this `create` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info(
  id integer,
  status integer
)
```

since you want the `id`s to have values `1-10` make the `id` `primary key` (so it will be `auto increment` starting from `1`) and the column status to have a default value of `0`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info(
  id integer primary key,
  status integer default 0
)
```

Now when you want to insert a new row all you have to do is execute this statement:

```
insert into info default values;
```

This inserts a row with the next `id` (for a new table the `id` will start from 1) and `status`=`0`.
So use a loop to insert 10 rows:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    c.execute('insert into info default values')
```